# What if we want to access DOM elements and change them inside useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code here that I want to update inside this hook when an element outside useEffect is updated.

```
const handleSelectHost = (selectedHosts) => {
  if (selectedHosts.length >= 1) {

    setMultiDeleteHost(true);
  } else {
    setMultiDeleteHost(false);
  }
  const updatedMultiHostName = updateObject(multiHostName, {
    selectValue: selectedHosts,
  });
  setMultiHostName(updatedMultiHostName);
};



useEffect(() => {
        let isUnmount = false;
        let selectedHosts = [];
        if (props.hosts) {
          console.log(deleteRef);
          const rows = props.hosts.map((row, key) => {
            const initiatorNames = []
            const initiatorTarget = []
            const initiatorConnected = []
            const initiatorDisconnected = []
            for (let initiator of row.initiators) {
              initiatorNames.push(initiator.name)
              initiatorTarget.push(initiator.target)
            }
            row.initiators.filter(
              (initiator) => {
                if (initiator["Connection Status"] === "Connected") {
                  initiatorConnected.push(initiator)
                } else initiatorDisconnected.push(initiator)
              }
            );
            return {
              name: row.name,
              ip: <div style={{ width: 100 }}>{row.ip}</div>,
              initiators: <div>{[...new Set(initiatorNames)].map((item, index) => { return <span key={index} className="target px-2">{item}</span> })}</div>,
              connection_Status: `${initiatorConnected.length} Connected, ${initiatorDisconnected.length} Disconnected`,
              access_control: row.acc,
              type: row.type,
              actions: [
                <div  key={row.name} className="d-flex align-items-center">
                  <MDBBtn
                    onClick={(e) => handleShowDetail(row)}
                    size="sm"
                    outline
                    color=""
                    className="primary-color"
                  >
                    Detail
                  </MDBBtn>
                  <MDBDropdown key={key} dropright className="text-center">
                    <MDBDropdownToggle
                      color=""
                      className="z-depth-0 hoverable py-1 px-2 my-0"
                    >
                      <MDBIcon icon="fas fa-ellipsis-v dynamic-text-color" />
                    </MDBDropdownToggle>
                    <MDBDropdownMenu color="" basic>
                      <MDBDropdownItem onClick={() => handleHostEdit(row)}>
                        Edit Host
                      </MDBDropdownItem>
                      <MDBDropdownItem
                        disabled={multiDeleteHost ? true : false} 
//How can I get and change the value of the state when my status changes in the table that is an option?

                        onClick={() => handleDeleteHost(row.name)}
                      >
                        Delete Host
                      </MDBDropdownItem>
                      <MDBDropdownItem
                        hidden={row.ip ? false : true}
                        onClick={() => handleDeleteIp(row.ip, row.name)}
                      >
                        Delete Ip
                      </MDBDropdownItem>
                    </MDBDropdownMenu>
                  </MDBDropdown>
                </div>,
              ],
            };
          });
          const updateDataTable = updateObject(dataTable, {
            rows: rows,
            options: updateObject(dataTable.options, {
              onRowSelectionChange: (
                currentRowsSelected,
                allRowsSelected,
                rowsSelected
              ) => {
                selectedHosts.length = 0;
                for (let index of rowsSelected) {
                  props.hosts[index] && selectedHosts.push(props.hosts[index].name);
                }
                handleSelectHost(selectedHosts);
                fetchRef()
              },
              textLabels: {
                body: {
                  noMatch: !rows.length ? "Sorry, no matching records found" : "",
                },
              },
            }),
          });
          if (!isUnmount) {
            setDataTable(updateDataTable);
          }
        }
        return () => {
          isUnmount = true;
          selectedHosts = [];
          setMultiDeleteHost(false);
          setMultiHostName({ selectValue: [] });
        };
      }, [props.hosts]);
```

I want the check box of the line to be selected and the delete host option to be disabled in drop, but because it is inside the use effect, it is not possible
[image]

Comment: None of this code makes any sense. Why are you doing all of that *data processing and JSX creation* inside a `useEffect` hook? Why are you trying to *imperatively* manipulate the DOM *inside a `useEffect` hook*? The *entire idea* of React is that your views are pure functions of your application state. All of that processing should be happening in a *component*, that is *pure* and rendered from state. Since the derived stuff is from *props* why are you using `useEffect` *at all*? The checkbox is the *least* of your problems. Go back [to square one](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Revised Answer

The first step would be the render for the checkbox. I will assume the checkbox component to be as follows:

```
const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
return(
    ....
    <Checkbox {...props} value={checked} onChange={()=> setChecked(prevChecked => !prevChecked)} />
    ....
);
```

Secondly, I do not know whether or not you are using a UI Library, but you can make use of the disabled/hidden property to the MenuItem component, or return from the onClick handler of the MenuItem depending on the value of ***checked*** state. You won't need useEffect for something so simple, although you can opt to use it.

---

That is what the useRef hook is for. This is how you make use of it:

First of all, you declare a ref variable using the useRef Hook

```
const elementRef = useRef(null);
```

Then, you attach it to your desired element present in the JSX you return from this function.

```
return(
    ...
    <DesiredElement {...props} ref={elementRef} />
    ...
);
```

Now, inside the useEffect, the elementRef will no longer be null because the component will have been mounted. So you can get access to that element using the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const element = elementRef.current;
    console.log(element);
    // Should return <DesiredElement {...props} />
}, []);
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the problem was not solved. I don't want this to happen only once. I want the option to be disabled and re-enabled every time the checkbox is selected, only the same element with the title delete host.       <MDBDropdownItem
                    {...props} ref={elementRef}
                    disabled={multiDeleteHost ? true : false}
                    onClick={() => handleDeleteHost(row.name)}
                  >
                    Delete Host
                  </MDBDropdownItem>

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    const element = elementRef.current;
    console.log(element);
    // Should return <DesiredElement {...props} />
}, []); The code must be repeated again?

Comment: Wait, so do you want the MenuItem to be disabled after the checkbox is checked?

Comment: yes item Delete to menu item

Comment: Ok then, I will update the answer so that checking the checkbox disables the MenuItem